# Updating integer within string row for each instance in R dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, instance

I have a dataframe similar to the following reproducible one in which one column contains HTML code:

```
ID <- c(15, 25, 90, 1, 23, 543)

HTML <- c("[demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]", "<text-ali>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]", "[social_isolation][1]<div></table<div><text-align>[social_isolation_date][1]", "<text-align>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]", "<div>[demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]", "[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]</table")

df <- data.frame(ID, HTML)
```

[image]

I would like to update the integer within the square brackets of the `HTML` column to reflect each instance of repeat. For example, the second time that [demography_form] appears in a row, I would like the square brackets following it to be [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpPu6.png):

[image]

What's the best way of going about doing this? I was thinking of somehow creating an instance column and then using that to update the value in the square brackets, deleting it at the end? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grouping column from the substring inside the `[]` from HTML column, replace the digits inside the `[]` with the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) using `str_replace_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = str_extract(HTML, "\\[(\\w+)\\]", group =1)) %>% 
  mutate(HTML = str_replace_all(HTML, "\\[(\\d+)\\]", 
     sprintf("[%d]", row_number()))) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     ID HTML                                                                           
  <dbl> <chr>                                                                          
1    15 [demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]          
2    25 <text-ali>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]  
3    90 [social_isolation][1]<div></table<div><text-align>[social_isolation_date][1]   
4     1 <text-align>[geography_form][2]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][2]
5    23 <div>[demography_form][2]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][2]     
6   543 [geography_form][3]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][3]</table
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for this example, but for some reason is not updating the numbers in my real-world example and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: @Andrea You need `df <- df %>...` i.e. assign it to original ddata

Comment: thanks I have that but the issue is that it increments each row by 1 without keeping track of instances as I had hoped. I'm trying to troubleshoot

Comment: @Andrea Is the grouping correct.  Can yu check the grp column before `select(-grp)`

Comment: @Andrea Can you use `dput` to get the structure of input data so i can test i.e. `dput(head(df, 20))`

Comment: Thank you, I have doen that here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ivjnnmqk1qi00xcxm0hrw/dput.docx?dl=0&rlkey=hltjp1kaqj48cuipmysn4pozw

Comment: @Andrea it is in word format, which is kind of messing up while i copy

Comment: that's ok thank you I figured it out! I appreciate your help on this matter and your answers!